# When I do update I get a message of success but nothing changes. What a im doing wrong?

Tags: php, html

This is my DB :

Table: Terras_Sico

Column---------------Type--------------     Null
id  ----------------------              int(11) ----------- No
nome -----------------              varchar(250)    ---No
preco_publico-------        decimal(10,2)-- No
imagem  ---------------         varchar(250)--  No
nota_prova  -----------     varchar(250)    --No
produtor_enologo ---   varchar(250)--   No
ano          ---------------------       varchar(250)-- No
tipo----------------------              varchar(250)

This is my code :

```html
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', true);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 
 error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE );
 
 require_once 'dbconfig.php';
 
 if(isset($_GET['edit_id']) && !empty($_GET['edit_id']))
 {
  $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
  $stmt_edit = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT nome, preco_publico, imagem, nota_prova, produtor_enologo, ano, tipo FROM Terras_Sico WHERE id =:uid');
  $stmt_edit->execute(array(':uid'=>$id));
  $edit_row = $stmt_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  extract($edit_row);
 }
 else
 {
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
 
 
 
 if(isset($_POST['btn_save_updates']))
 {
  $nome = utf8_decode( $_POST[nome] );
  $preco_publico = utf8_decode($_POST[preco_publico]);
  $nota_prova = utf8_decode($_POST[nota_prova]);
  $produtor_enologo = utf8_decode($_POST[produtor_enologo]);
  $ano = utf8_decode($_POST[ano]);
  $tipo = utf8_decode($_POST[tipo]);
   
  $imgFile = $_FILES['u_imagem']['name'];
  $tmp_dir = $_FILES['u_imagem']['tmp_name'];
  $imgSize = $_FILES['u_imagem']['size'];
     
  if($imgFile)
  {
   $upload_dir = '../../../../d.sesnando/'; // upload directory 
   $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
   $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
   $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
   if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions))
   {   
    if($imgSize < 5000000)
    {
     unlink($upload_dir.$edit_row['imagem']);
     move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
    }
    else
    {
     $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large it should be less then 5MB";
    }
   }
   else
   {
    $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";  
   } 
  }
  else
  {
   // if no image selected the old image remain as it is.
   $userpic = $edit_row['imagem']; // old image from database
  } 
      
  
  // if no error occured, continue ....
  if(!isset($errMSG))
  {
   $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('UPDATE Terras_Sico 
              SET nome=:unome, 
               preco_publico=:upreco_publico, 
               imagem=:uimagem,
            nota_prova=:unota_prova, 
               produtor_enologo=:uprodutor_enologo, 
               ano=:uano,
            tipo=:utipo
               WHERE id=:uid');
   $stmt->bindParam(':unome',$nome);
   $stmt->bindParam(':upreco_publico',$preco_publico);
   $stmt->bindParam(':uimagem',$imagem);
   $stmt->bindParam(':unota_prova',$nota_prova);
   $stmt->bindParam(':uprodutor_enolog',$produtor_enologo);
   $stmt->bindParam(':uano',$ano);
   $stmt->bindParam(':utipo',$tipo);
   $stmt->bindParam(':uid',$id);
    
   if($stmt->execute()){
    ?>
                <script>
    alert('Successfully Updated ...');
    window.location.href='index.php';
    </script>
                <?php
   }
   else{
    $errMSG = "Sorry Data Could Not Updated !";
   }
  
  }
  
      
 }
 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Upload, Insert, Update, Delete an Image using PHP MySQL - Coding Cage</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- custom stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
 
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../insercao/panel.php" title='Programming Blog'>Inicio</a>
            
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Voltar</a>
        </div>
 
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">


 <div class="page-header">
     <h1 class="h2">Update Produto <a class="btn btn-default" href="index.php"> Todos os produtos </a></h1>
    </div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
 
    
    <?php
 if(isset($errMSG)){
  ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; <?php echo $errMSG; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
   
    
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
 
    <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Nome</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Preço ao Público</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="preco_publico" value="<?php echo $preco_publico; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Nota de Prova</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nota_prova" value="<?php echo $nota_prova; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Produtor/Énologo</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="produtor_enologo" value="<?php echo $produtor_enologo; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Ano</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="ano" value="<?php echo $ano; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Tipo</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="tipo" value="<?php echo $tipo; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Imagem</label></td>
        <td>
         <p><img src="../../../../d.sesnando/<?php echo $imagem; ?>" height="150" width="150" /></p>
         <input class="input-group" type="file" name="imagem" accept="image/*" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btn_save_updates" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Update
        </button>
        
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="index.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span> cancelar </a>
        
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
    
</form>


<div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>tutorial link !</strong> <a href="http://www.codingcage.com/2016/02/upload-insert-update-delete-image-using.html">Coding Cage</a>!
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With question like _"Why isn't this code working?_ / _"why am I getting this error"_ it is difficult for volunteer on SO to help you. In this case you should _include the desired behavior_ too and, if possible, include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry, i´m new here. 
So I needed help, because my update says it did, but it does not change anything. Do I have to create a new post or can it be in this one?

Comment: Sure, you can edit your own post. You don't need to post another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed a character in your parameters.

wrong:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':uprodutor_enolog',$produtor_enologo);
```

right:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':uprodutor_enologo',$produtor_enologo);
```

Comment: Thank´s for answer!! I change and now when i click update,
i get update successfully, but nothing changes